# Ruby MatchData post_match unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby, regex

I am comparing the special variable `$'` to method `MatchData#post_match`. Special variable works fine, but the method post_match fails.

This works fine:

```
m = /b/.match("abc")
# => #<MatchData "b">
m.post_match
# => "c"

"abc".match(/b/)
# => #<MatchData "b">
$'
# => "c"
```

This fails:

```
"abc".match(/b/)
# => #<MatchData "b">
MatchData.post_match
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `post_match' for MatchData
```

I am expecting the same output `'c'`. Why does it fail? What am I missing?

Comment: You are calling `post_match` on a class `MatchData`, but it's not a class method - you have to call it on an instance of `MatchData`.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems that special variable $' is better. What would be a good example where post_match is superior? Why create MatchData object if the magic happens with Special Variables already behind the scenes?

Comment: Magic is a first enemy of a good developer and is an evil in general.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `post_match` on an instance of the matchdata.

```
match_data = "abc".match(/b/)
# => #<MatchData "b">
match_data.post_match
# => "c"
```

---

Global variables with the `$` prefix is difficult to handle. It can be changed anywhere, and it is difficult to keep track of that. In addition, the variable `$'` keeps changing every time you do a regex match. This can become a trouble when you are doing regex matches in nested loops; whenever you do something in the inner loop, you can mess up the last match in an outer loop. And vice versa. Or when you want to refer to a previous match after doing a different match, you are in a trouble.

By having a match data instance, you can assign that as a local variable, and keep track of multiple match data in complicated situations.